# Trigger a singleclick event

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I use OpenLayers 6, and I would like to trigger a singleclick event on the map automatically from a pixel.
I searched in the documentation, but I didn't find anything (or I probably did'nt understand!)

Here my code for the moment:

```
map.on("singleclick", singleClick)

if (centroid.length > 0) {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        let pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(centroid)
        console.log(pixel)
        //TODO trigger singleclick function
    }, 1)
}
```

I don't copy/paste the code about singleClick function, it works with a user click.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What properties of the event does the function use?  It could be as simple as calling `singleClick({coordinate: centroid, pixel: pixel});`

Comment: Thanks, but I need a real event for `singleClick(e)`

Comment: Use map.dispatchEvent method.

Comment: `map.dispatchEvent ({ type: 'singleClick', coordinate: centroid, pixel: pixel })`